# Make text hyperlink in <textarea>

Tags: php, jquery

I have a textarea which post plane text to  mysql db table. Now I want to add some hyper references in that text.
how can I do this?
And I don't want to use any editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, `textarea` is a plain text input control. You need to allow rich-text/mark-up interpreted correctly using [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)

**textarea**

> The TEXTAREA element creates a multi-line text input control. User agents should use the contents of this element as the initial value of the control and should render this text initially.

Comment: most of the modern wysiwyg editor support javascript mode (source mode) already

Answer (score 0):

**Use html_entities of php**

```
    $textarea_code = htmlentities($_REQUEST['text_area_name']);
            $b = html_entity_decode($textarea_code);
            $textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($b);
echo $textarea;
```