# Do any browsers or add-ons support clickable hyperlinks in textareas?

Tags: html, textarea

Top Google results are a couple years old:

[Make text hyperlink in <textarea>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496553/make-text-hyperlink-in-textarea)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/340112/How-we-insert-hyperlink-in-textarea-in-textbox

And mostly people saying "that makes no sense, why would a plain-text control support that?".

I am creating a web version of an application that already has a Windows, iOS and Android version.  On all 3 of those platforms they support clickable links even though the user cannot apply any special formatting to any of the text, and the control only allows and returns plain-text.  In Windows it is a feature of the RichEdit control class, which yes can have formatted text, but it has a plain-text mode also (what I use).  In Android I think it is called auto-link, and they do it for phone numbers, addresses, email addresses, URLs, etc.

So has this feature just alluded the web app world so far?  Or is it at least possible with certain browsers and/or add-on/extensions for those browsers?  I'd at least like to tell end-users "if you really want that feature, install this add-on, or get this browser".

I want to display an editable text field, with clickable links, that does not allow any formatting and only requires me to load plain-text in it, and only returns plain-text when I query the value (for usage with AJAX/JavaScript).

Comment: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: In a textarea? No. In a contenteditable element? Sure.

Comment: [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) supports this sort of thing as well..

Comment: re: contenteditable - http://jsfiddle.net/erikwoods/Ee3yC/   playing around with this doesn't look like it auto-detects URLs as I type.  It does look like some versions of IE might auto-convert when I paste something, but still not as you type.  Also appears to be a mess forcing these things to be plain-text only, AND still get the hyperlinks.  Again, maybe that seems obvious to most web developers, that you wouldn't get it "for free", but outside the web world it is common and easy -- so was just hoping.